# Decrease form opacity

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

When I click on `Button1`, if `Form1((me))` opacity is less than 90 then `Form1's((me))` opacity should decrease by 9%

This is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Me.Opacity > 90 Then
        Me.Opacity = -9
    End If
End Sub
```

and it's not working

Comment: Check out my solution if it works. Do remember that you should be using 0.9 instead of 90 because the highest number value for opacity is 1(100%). 90% should be 0.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few errors. First, `>` is more, not less. Next, opacity has range 0-1, not 0-100. And last, `Me.Opacity=-9` doesn't decrease it by 9, it makes it -9.

It's unclear if you want to decrease opacity by 9% of current opacity or by 0.09.

This decreases by 0.09:

```
If Me.Opacity < 0.9 Then
    Me.Opacity -= 0.09
End If
```

And this by 9% of current value:

```
If Me.Opacity < 0.9 Then
    Me.Opacity -= Me.Opacity * 0.09
End If
```

If you want, you can set bottom limit:

```
If Me.Opacity < 0.9 AndAlso Me.Opacity > 0.2 Then
    'Decrease opacity
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for. Based on your statement, if the form's opacity is less than 90 (which means opacity value is less than 0.9), then 9% of the current opacity is subtracted to the current opacity. This also means that the button click code will only execute when opacity is at 0.89 or lower. It continues to subtract 9% whenever you click the button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Me.Opacity < 0.9 Then
        Me.Opacity -= (Me.Opacity * 0.09)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`>` means "More Than" not less. Also `= -9` assigns a value of -9 to the opacity. What you want is

```
If Me.Opacity < 0.9 Then
  Me.Opacity = Math.Max(0, Me.Opacity - 0.09)
End If
```

Edit: Opacity as a value ranges from 0 to 1 (which, as displayed in % means 0% to 100%). My bad.

This assigns a value of `Current value - 9%` to the current opacity, so it decreases it by 9 percent. It also makes sure that the opacity never drops under 0 (that's what Math.Max() is for here).

Comment: No problem. You should mark it as answered, so the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   If Me.Opacity > 90 Then
   Me.Opacity = Me.Opacity – 9
   End If
End Sub
```

**(Or)**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   While Me.Opacity > 90 Then
   Me.Opacity = Me.Opacity – 9
   End While 
End Sub
```